# Add tag for game "Planetary Annihilation"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I'd like to ask a question about the game [Planetary Annihilation](http://www.uberent.com/pa/) but there's no tag for it yet, and I don't have enough rep to create one. Would someone else be so kind as to create it for me?